# Want to log my wordpress users in with user id and password

Tags: wordpress, authentication, userid

I want a procedure that i should follow to make the users log in to their profile with the user id and password on my wordpress website

Answer (score 0):

there is a useful plugin as **WP Activity Log**. it has multiple options that helps you to monitor users log info. so you can Follow the using instruction of plugin.

Comment: i need to allow users to login with their user id and pay instead of email